# How to make 3 equal square divs that fits the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm programming a blog website for my sister, but I got into a problem I can't solve..

I would like to make her site look like the following:

the posts should be inside square divs, and one row 3 divs. But I'm not able to do that. I would like to make it expand and fit the screen, with margins. (like in the following website: https://www.chloefromthewoods.com/)

I have the following code:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="posts">
            <div id="post1" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-image: url(img1.JPG)">
                    Post...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post2" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-image: url(img2.JPG)">
                    Post...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post3" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-image: url(img3.JPG)">
                    Post...
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainDiv
{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;

    margin: 0 auto 300px auto;

    overflow: hidden;
}
#posts
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.post
{
/* Make it square and fit the screen */
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.postDiv
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But it's not working..: [image]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/9qs34mgw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

**HTML**

```
#mainDiv{height:300px;background-color:#ff8000;}

#posts
{
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
}

#post1{width:33%;min-width:400px;min-height:400px;flex-grow:1;}
#post2{width:33%;min-width:400px;min-height:400px;flex-grow:1;}
#post3{width:33%;min-width:400px;min-height:400px;flex-grow:1;}

.postDiv{height:100%;}
```

**CSS**

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="posts">
            <div id="post1" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-color: green">
                    A bit longer post
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post2" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-color: blue">
                    Post Post
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post3" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv" style="background-color: red">
                    Post...
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox:

This will produce 3 divs, even spaced and inline. They will auto expand as needed. It seems like a lot of CSS, but that is just because I included the prefixes.

HTML

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.posts {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

.post:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.post:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.post:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }
```

Comment: It makes 3 perfectly fitting divs but width different width values and not squares http://i.imgur.com/h1ZlEMU.jpg, btw I updated the post with JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get squares is to use the padded box trick: set `height: 0; padding-bottom: 30%;` on the individual posts (items) - this assumes `margin-left: 5%;` Vertical padding is based on parent's width, so `padding-bottom: 100%` would make the post divs grow to the same height as the parent's width. Setting the bottom padding to 30% makes the box grow to 100% of the width of the box, making a square. Set `display: inline-block;` on the items and `font-size: 0` on the parent div to remove the excess pixels added by using inline-block.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mainDiv
{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 800px;

    margin: 0 auto 300px auto;

    overflow: hidden;
}
#posts {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    }
    
    .post {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30%;
      font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 5%;
      height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;


    }

.post:first-child {
     background: green;
     margin-left: 0;
   }

.post:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.post:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
    }
.postDiv
{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
<div id="posts">
            <div id="post1" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv">
                    A bit longer post
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post2" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv">
                    Post Post
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post3" class="post">
                <div class="postDiv">
                    Post...
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```